# pivot table to 3D graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have 3 columns on my table, `A (str)`, `B (str)` and `C (str)`. On my pivot table, column `C` is broken down to its sub-categories, say `c1 (str)` to `c5 (str)`. As these subcategories are the headings, the values they contain are the counts of `A` and `B` happening together with respect to  that subcategory. Consider this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': '100 200 100 200'.split(),
                   'B': 'foo foo bar bar'.split(),
                   'c1': np.arange(4),
                   'c2': '5 0 8 2'.split(), 
                   'c3': '0 2 1 0'.split(), 
                   'c4': np.arange(4), 
                   'c5': '9 7 4 3'.split()})
```

I can use the 3D column chart options on excel to create 3D visualization, such that the values of `c1` to `c5` columns appear on the `z-axis`, i.e. the height of the columns. Excel joins columns `A` and `B` together on one axis of the chart.

Question:
How can I draw a similar 3D column graph in python?

I tried using matplotlib, and the example here [3D Bar Chart with Matplotlib](https://pythonprogramming.net/3d-bar-chart-matplotlib-tutorial/) like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x3 = df.columns[2:]
y3 = df['B'] + df['A']
z3 = np.zeros(5)

dx = np.ones(5)
dy = np.ones(5)
dz = df.iloc[:, 2:]

ax1.bar3d(x3, y3, z3, dx, dy, dz)

ax1.set_xlabel('A')
ax1.set_ylabel('B')
ax1.set_zlabel('C Count')
```

but I am getting the following error which I think is caused by having both 1D and 2D arrays.

````
<ipython-input-21-c88ff0ea352d> in <module>
     10 dz = df.iloc[:, 2:]
     11 
---> 12 ax1.bar3d(x3, y3, z3, dx, dy, dz)
     13 
     14 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in bar3d(self, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color, zsort, shade, *args, **kwargs)
   2480 
   2481         x, y, z, dx, dy, dz = np.broadcast_arrays(
-> 2482             np.atleast_1d(x), y, z, dx, dy, dz)
   2483         minx = np.min(x)
   2484         maxx = np.max(x + dx)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in broadcast_arrays(*args, **kwargs)
    257     args = [np.array(_m, copy=False, subok=subok) for _m in args]
    258 
--> 259     shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
    260 
    261     if all(array.shape == shape for array in args):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_shape(*args)
    191     # use the old-iterator because np.nditer does not handle size 0 arrays
    192     # consistently
--> 193     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    194     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    195     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape```
````

Comment: `x3,y3,z3` should be one-dimensional and of the same length. Your `z3` is a 2D array, you should use some sort of `meshgrid` as in the linked answer.